# Circular Progress bar for onClick audio in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

I have a audio and onClick I need to make a circle progress that changes with time.Any code example suggestions or advice regarding this.

Comment: My advice is to share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Your question is not valid . you may need to improve your question immediatly...